# How to preserve Fragment List View Contents?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Preamble: I am using ActionBarSherlock, Target SDK is 17 (Android 4.2), Min SDK is 5 (Android 2.0)

**Situation:**

I've got a fragment in my app, which presents some kind of login. It allows the user to have several user accounts on device (because Android < 4.2 didn't have system support for that and our users seem to use that due to device sharing).

The fragment layout consists of a listview and on large-landscape also a button to add new accounts (otherwise via overflow menu available).

The listview is attached to a BaseAdapter-Derivate called "AccountAdapter", which gets the accounts from a database and creating corresponding child views per account via layoutinflater. There are 3 Possibilities: User provided both Login and Password / User provided only login / User provided nothing. Therefore, there are 3 different Layouts for those cases, where the missing data is requested via EditText-Elements and stored data is shown via TextView. Also, the layouts with missing data provide a checkbox for store the missing data and a submit-button. If all data is provided, the onclicklistener for the missing submit button gets directly attached to the account root view.
The onclicklistener messages the entered data to the network code class and modifys the adapter mode; after that, the adapter only shows the selected entry, but with the "progress" view, to visualize the current action to the user ("User XXX is being logged in, please stand by...").

This already works well.

**Problem:**

On orientation changes, all entered data gets lost. Entered login data, passwords, information about if the login data should be stored.

**Layouts:**

```
<!-- layout/main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/main_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- layout-large-land/main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/main_fragment_sidebar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_sidebar_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/main_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- layout/fragment_login.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/fragment_login_accountlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- layout-large-land/fragment_login.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@id/fragment_login_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/string_fragment_login" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/fragment_login_accountlist"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_login_accountlist_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- layout/view_login_account_new.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string_view_login_account_profileimage_contentdescription"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_kb" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string_view_login_account_username_hint"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string_view_login_account_password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_storecredentials"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_password"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_storecredentials_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_storecredentials"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_submit_text" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- layout/view_login_account_progress.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string_view_login_account_profileimage_contentdescription"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_kb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:ems="10"
         >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_progress_text" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- layout/view_login_account_stored_password.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string_view_login_account_profileimage_contentdescription"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_kb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:ems="10"
         >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_password_text"
         />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- layout/view_login_account_stored_username.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_login_account_profileimage_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string_view_login_account_profileimage_contentdescription"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_kb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string_view_login_account_username_hint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string_view_login_account_password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_storecredentials"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_password"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_login_account_profileimage"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_storecredentials_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/view_login_account_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_login_account_storecredentials"
        android:text="@string/string_view_login_account_submit_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code:**

The code both doesn't implement onSaveInstanceState and onConfigurationChange yet.
(whole quotation would be too long imho, > 1.000 lines of code)

```
public class MessengerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    FrameLayout fragmentSidebar = null;
    FrameLayout fragmentContent = null;

    Content     content         = null;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    boolean     hasSidebar      = false;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        content = Content.getInstance(this);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        captureFragmentViews();

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------

            gotoLogin();

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------

        }
        else {

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------

        }


        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Disabled through android manifest at the moment

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onConfigurationChanged");

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void captureFragmentViews() {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        fragmentSidebar = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_sidebar);
        fragmentContent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_content);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        if ((fragmentSidebar != null) && (fragmentContent != null)) {

            hasSidebar = true;

        }
        else {

            hasSidebar = false;

        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoLogin() {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Fragment fragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(this,
                LoginFragment.class.getName());

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (hasSidebar) {

            ft.add(R.id.main_fragment_content, fragment);
            fragmentSidebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else {

            ft.add(R.id.main_fragment_content, fragment);

        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        ft.commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoSignup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoContactList(int filterId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoConversation(int userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoOnlineStatusList(int categoryId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void gotoSettings(int categoryId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

I check for whether savedInstanceState is set or not in the main activity, so my activity is already "prepared" in terms of fragment recreation.

Fragment checks for whether the adapter already exists or not before creating and attaching it to the listview.
But: As far as my understanding is, even if the "recreated" fragment use the same Adapter, "by default" all getViews() get recalled and therefore create a new instance of the view with "resetted" contents.

The AccountAdapter gets dedicated "Account"-Objects with user-id, username, password from the database. Also, "Account" could be extended to hold additional data, like to cache the view.

My idea was to implement a getView like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        final Account account = (Account) getItem(position);
        View view = null;

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (account == null) {

            return view;

        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (account.view != null) {

            return account.view;

        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [...]
    }
```

But then I noticed, that the AccountAdapter didn't survive the recreation, Android re-instantiates the LoginFragment class.

**What I need:**

- How to recover the data from the listview content formulars / how to preserve the AccountAdapter and its associated views
- Tips on how to optimize and improve my architectural design

Comment: Please post the way in which you attach the fragment to the Activity.

Comment: *edit: added activity code

Comment: what is Content ? Do you use backstack when adding your fragments.. between steps?

Comment: Content is a class which decides the data source; either to use the database backend (cached) or retrieving data from the network. Also, Content provides callbacks on Events like "logged in" and "global" data functions like to retrieve the list of user accounts from database. I don't use the backstack yet, but I like to do so, when I've got multiple fragments, even if I am not sure yet. As you can see in the activity code, there are no other fragments yet.

Comment: what do you do `if (savedInstanceState!=null) . You still add fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your code if you add a `Fragment` every time the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` get's called.

You should add a `Fragment` or the first `Fragment` only when the `Activity` get's created for the first time .

```
if(savedInstanceState==null){
     addFragment();
}
```

if this is not `null` your `Activity` gets re-created, and it will also re-add your previous `Fragments`. Evan if you have more `Fragments` in the `backstack` they will all be put back in your `Activity`.

To keep the data in your fragments, you should either use `setRetainInstance(true);` on your `Fragments` `onCreate()` method, or use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` to save the specific data.

Comment: The Activity-Code is exactly as posted; therefore, if savedInstanceState is not set, there will  be no fragment created. However, `setRetainInstance(true)` solved my issue, as now (after a few modifications) the Fragment didn't get reinstantiated but only restarted - thanks :)